# Manipulate -> Pause Play at specific conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

How can I pause play in Manipulate when a condition is met ?
Here is an example:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 10], {i, 1, 10, 
  AnimationRate -> 3, RefreshRate -> 60, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

When I press the "Play" Buttom, `i` increases.
Now, I want the animation to stop automatically, when `i` reaches a certain value, say `i=5`.

**How can I do that ?**

**EDIT:** Thanks a lot for the great answers.
Would it be possible to implement the following:

1. One can define points for which play will stop, for instance, at i=2, i=4, and i=8
2. When i== One of the points -> Then play will stop, if I press the play buttom again, then it will continue to run until the next break point:

Example:

i==2 -> Stop

Manually: Press Play
--> Continues

i==4 -> Stop

Manually: Press Play
--> Continues

etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Manipulate` by default uses `Manipulator` which doesn't seem to support dynamic values for the `AnimationRunning` option. However you could use `ControlType -> Animator`.

Here's a possible approach where by adding two extra control variables I can stop the animation after `i` reaches 5 on the first run.

```
Manipulate[
  If[initialRun && i >= 5, running = False; initialRun = False];
  Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 10]
  ,
  {initialRun, {True, False}, ControlType -> None},
  {running, {True, False}, ControlType -> None},
  {i, 1, 10, ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> 3, 
     RefreshRate -> 60, AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[running]}
]
```

[image: Manipulate with one animation breakpoint]

Note that if the user interacts with the animator before it gets paused by the Manipulate, the pausing will still happen whenever the value of `i` is 5 or greater first.

For a version with more than one breakpoint, replace the `initialRun` boolean with an integer counting how many runs have happened:

```
With[{breakPoints = {2, 4, 8}},
  Manipulate[
    If[runNumber <= Length[breakPoints] && i >= breakPoints[[runNumber]],
      running = False; runNumber++
    ];
    Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 10]
    ,
    {runNumber, 1, ControlType -> None},
    {running, {True, False}, ControlType -> None},
    {i, 1, 10, ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> 3, RefreshRate -> 60, AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[running]}
  ]
]
```

[image: Manipulate with several animation breakpoints]

Comment: +1 Good idea, it seems I am not able to think in this heat. :)

Comment: +1, I arrived too late.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great idea, but I would need it to stop when i=5 and then when I push the play button it should continue. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please see the recent edit for more information

Comment: Wow ! This is perfect ! Very well done !! Thank you very much. :))

Comment: I have a problem. When I decide to stop the playback and do some few steps backwards by clicking on the "-" symbol, and then I press play again, it will not stop to play at the specific locations. Do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: @james the current solution only uses the breakpoints on the first runthrough (so if a breakpoint is triggered once, it doesn't get used again, but the next breakpoint on the list will still trigger).

Comment: @Gerli Thanks for your answer. Can it be changed such that it always triggers ?

Answer (score 2):

The credit goes to @Gerli, who arrived first. Difference is that mine uses [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html)

```
DynamicModule[
 {s = True},
 Manipulate[
  If[i > 5, s = False, s = True];
  Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 10],
  {
   i, 1, 10
   , ControlType -> Animator
   , AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[s]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I would need it to stop when i=5 and then when I push the play button it should continue. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please have a look at the recent edit. Thanks :)